# Subsurface scattering always gives red glow

Tags: light, subsurface-scattering

I am trying to create a wax type material with subsurface scattering for a set of hands but whatever I do, the scattering produces a red glow (see attached image), making the wax hands look like actual (weirdly white) hands. Is this physically correct or did I make a mistake somewhere? I tried adjusting the SSS color, background color, and light color, none of these got rid of the red tint. Turning SSS off completely does make it go away.

I am using Blender 2.92

[image]

Thank you for your help!

[image: Red glow visible at fingers]

Comment: did yout weak the Subsurface Radius values? they set the RGB subsurface rays...

Comment: Hello :). Your SSS depth is too high - 100-300mm. Human skin SSS is only ~5 mm deep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tweak the *Subsurface Radius* values. They will determine the RGB coloration.

As the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/properties/subsurface_scattering.html) says, *this value corresponds to the average length the light travels between each bounce. The longer the path length is, the further the light is allowed to scatter. This is the main source of a material’s perceived « scatter color. » A material like skin will have a higher red radius than green and blue. Subsurface scattering is the diffusion of light beneath the surface.*

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that indeed fixed it. Thank you for your quick response!